# Network Simulation Cradle with Linux Stack 2.6.35

Tags: networking, simulation, cradle

I am struggling to integrate the network stack of Linux Kernel 2.6.35 with the Network Simulation Cradle (http://www.wand.net.nz/~stj2/nsc/).

Has anyone done it before ? If yes please reply.

I am getting an error saying : fatal error: when writing output to : Broken pipe.

Well, I cannot proceed further explaining what I have done till now, as that would make no sense if no one here has worked with this Network Simulation Cradle.

So, if anyone has worked with this, please reply.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better asking off on the ns-3 mailing list, or emailing the author of the NSC directly.

Either way, you'll need to include more information in your question!